# Where did the Transformer embedding numbers come from?

Tags: bert-language-model, embedding, transformer-model, sentence-transformers

I'm a student studying Transformer. I want to ask, when I will vectorize words with Transformer BERT and get 768 vector dimensions for each word, I'm confused about where these numbers come from, is there a formula to calculate them? Or this vector has been defined according to the token index of each word on Transformer. I need an explanation of the concept. Thank You

```
array([[-0.6438617 , -0.16065954, -0.5565007 , ..., -0.25163442,
         0.07514413, -0.30617303],
       [-0.3400169 ,  0.10424673, -0.03935281, ..., -0.40216202,
         0.16795622, -0.4955315 ],
       [-0.34042516,  0.5039195 ,  0.02804005, ..., -0.23906936,
        -0.17713265, -0.28009415],
       ...,
       [-0.39777777, -0.84454346,  0.03105666, ..., -0.31586862,
        -0.15702638,  0.08373763],
       [-0.78589696,  0.01650803,  0.02775506, ..., -0.08069627,
         0.07355314, -0.38013673],
       [ 0.22893211,  0.862909  ,  0.06432542, ...,  0.3613814 ,
        -2.1936886 , -0.27759486]], dtype=float32)
```

So, I just want to know how to calculate these vectors to produce a number that varies both minuses and positives from -1 to 1. Thank you very much

Comment: These vectors are learned. Each vector represents a token therefore the tokenizer vocabulary has the same number of elements as the embedding layer.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I'm wondering about the same thing